# Checkbox Duplication

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to create an update page and i've completed most of the page, with exception to the checkbox section. For some reason that i've yet to figure out, the checkboxes are duplicated. I am using laravel.

[image]

This is the code for that particular section of the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Focus Area</label>
    <br>
    @foreach(FocusArea::all() as $focusArea)
        @if(isset($project))
            <div class="checkbox material checkbox-success">
                <label>
            @foreach($project->getIdsOfFocusAreas() as $selectedFocusArea)
                @if($selectedFocusArea == $focusArea->focus_area_id)
                    <input type="checkbox" name="focus-area[]" value="{{ $selectedFocusArea }}" checked>
                @else
                    <input type="checkbox" name="focus-area[]" value="{{ $selectedFocusArea }}">
                @endif
            @endforeach
                {{ $focusArea->name }}
                </label>
            </div>
            <br>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Some extra information:

1. The number of elements in the array generated by FocusArea::all() is 5.
2. The number of elements in the array generated by getIdsOfFocusAreas() is 2.

I know that it is duplicating twice because of point number 2, im just not exactly sure why it is duplicating in the first place.

Comment: This does not look like PHP. What is this? You should clarify.

Comment: You are printing it twice. Your foreach runs 2 times so there is two checkbox. You should change your logic.

Comment: @taco Hi, sorry i didnt state it in the question. it is php but used together with the Laravel framework.

Comment: You run a for-each loop for *each* label, that means you can have zero to many checkboxes within each label. This is logically flawed already on a fundamental level, try to draw on paper with a pencil first what you want the template to do, then just encode it afterwards. For example: If you have one checkbox per label, don't loop for the checkbox(es), just output one. Drawing this on paper (instead of using the computer) first, helps your mind to better grasp it (we learn by using our hands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Focus Area</label>
    <br>
    <?php $selectedFlug = 0; ?>
    @foreach(FocusArea::all() as $focusArea)
        @if(isset($project))
            <div class="checkbox material checkbox-success">
                <label>
                    @foreach($project->getIdsOfFocusAreas() as $selectedFocusArea)
                        @if($selectedFocusArea == $focusArea->focus_area_id)
                            <input type="checkbox" name="focus-area[]" value="{{ $selectedFocusArea }}"  {{ ($selectedFocusArea == $focusArea->focus_area_id) ? 'checked' : '' }} >
                            <?php $selectedFlug = 1; ?>
                            @break
                        @else 
                            <?php $selectedFlug = 0; ?>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                    @if($selectedFlug == 0)
                        <input type="checkbox" name="focus-area[]" value="{{ $focusArea->focus_area_id }}">
                    @endif
                    {{ $focusArea->name }}
                </label>
            </div>
            <br>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rimon thanks for your help, Your code manages to get rid of all the duplications except the first there is 2 checkboxes for eAsset.

Comment: Hi Rimon, did adding 'continue' into the code gets rid of the 2nd checkbox for eAsset for you? I've been trying to remove the remaining additional checkbox but i still can't manage it. My ide gives me a "cannot break/continue 1 level(s)"

Comment: i have updated my answer. check it working or not! I think now this will be fix.